# Problems with HttpInterceptor for jwt token refreshing in Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs, jwt, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using jwt for authentication. I'm having trouble with the refreshing. Probably I think it's due to my lack of experience in **rxjs** observables and operators. I get the refresh token from my backend using these methods of my **auth.service.ts**

```js
    getNewAccessToken(refreshToken: string){
        return this.httpClient.post<Token>(`${this.baseService.baseUrl}auth-token-refresh/`, { refresh: refreshToken }, this.baseService.httpOptions).pipe(
          map((response:Token) => {
            this.cookieService.set(environment.tokenAccessName, response.access, null, '/', null, null, 'Strict');
            return response;
          }
        ));
      }

      getAuthToken() { 
        return this.cookieService.get(this.tokenAccessName);
      }

      getRefreshToken() { 
        return this.cookieService.get(this.tokenRefreshName);
      }

      hasValidToken() {
        if (this.getAuthToken())
          return !helper.isTokenExpired(this.getAuthToken());
        else 
          return false;
      }
```

Here's my interceptor **auth-interceptor.ts**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpErrorResponse
  } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Token } from '../models/token';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    if (authToken) {
      if (this.authService.hasValidToken()) {
        request = this.addAuthenticationToken(request);
      } 
    } 

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        return this.handle401Error(request, next);
      } else {
        return throwError(error);
      }
    }));
  }

  handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const refreshToken = this.authService.getRefreshToken();
    this.authService.getNewAccessToken(refreshToken).subscribe(
      (response: Token) => {
        this.addAuthenticationToken(request);
        return next.handle(request);
      },
      error => throwError(error)
    )
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    return request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken),
    });
  }

}
```

My *ide* shows the following errors

```
Property 'intercept' in type 'AuthInterceptor' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'.
Type '(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type '(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
Property 'type' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'HttpUserEvent<any>'.
```

and also

```
Argument of type '(error: any) => void | Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
Type 'void | Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.
```

I think I probably mistaken with the return types, but I cannot figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Can we have the content of your auth-interceptor?

Comment: @htn thank you, I didn 't notice I pasted the wrong code

Comment: I understand what you intend to do. It is easy to find what is wrong: handle401Error should return an `Observable` (void here). The first `return throwError(error)` should be replaced by `throw error;`. For the second one, do not return anything in errorHandler of subscribe. However, it is not easy to give you a correct answer to what you are trying to do: when having a 401 error, try to refresh token before replaying the request (if you do not do it correctly you can fall into an infinite loop)

Comment: **throw error;** doesn't change anything. I keep getting the same errors. Speaking about the strategy of refreshing token when getting 401 response, I read plenty of tutorial explaining it, so I though it was right

Comment: It's a right way to do, but it's complex with the retry. An easier way to handle this is: locally check token validity, refresh if needed, and logout when getting 401. Well, I re-read your code: we don't send then refreshToken when getting a 401, but you use it to generate another token ... I advice you to find a working example.

Comment: When I get 401: first I request a new token using the refresh token I stored as cookie, then I insert it in the authorization header of my previously failed request to perform the retry, this time with a right token. In particular I was following this guide https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/#http-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

I finally get to a solution. May someone could try to improve it anyway
I made the following changes and now it works
Adding the *Observable>* to the *intercept* signature caused the first issue explained in my question to disappear. For the second one, I follow the advice in the question's comment.
**interceptor class**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.authService.hasValidToken()) {
      request = this.addAuthenticationToken(request);
    } 

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        } else {
           throw error;
        }
      }));
  } 

  handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authService.getNewAccessToken().pipe(
      switchMap((response: Token) => {
        return next.handle(this.addAuthenticationToken(request));
      })
    )
  }

  addAuthenticationToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const authToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}` 
      }
    });
  }

}
```

While the function in my **authentication service** from which I get the refresh token has been modified as

```
getNewAccessToken(){
    return this.httpClient.post<Token>(`${this.baseService.baseUrl}auth-token-refresh/`, { refresh: this.getRefreshToken() }, this.baseService.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((response:Token) => {
        this.cookieService.set(environment.tokenAccessName, response.access, null, '/', null, null, 'Strict');
      }
    ));
  }
```